# Optimizing multivariate function in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have a multivariate function that I want to optimize over one parameter:

```
cost <- function(theta, X, y) {
  m <- nrow(X)
  X <- as.matrix(X)
  J <- sum(-y * log(sigmoid(X %*% theta)) - (1-y) * log(1 - sigmoid(X %*% theta)))/m;
  return(J)
}
```

To optimize it, i use optim function. First, I create a wrapper, then use optim function to optimize wrapper function:

```
# X and y initialized before
initial_theta <- rep(0,ncol(X))
wrapper <- function(theta) cost(theta, X=X, y=y)
o <- optim(initial_theta, wrapper)
```

How to optimize a multivariate function with optim without creating additional functions?

Comment: you shouldn't need the wrapper at all -- `optim(initial_theta, cost, X=X, y=y)` should work

Comment: @BenBolker - Thanks, it works. Post it as an answer, if you want your answer to be accepted.

Comment: Go ahead and accept @Dason's, which says the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`optim` takes a `...` parameter which passes any addition input to the function of interest.  So you don't need to create a new function as long as the parameter you want to optimize over is the first parameter of the function of interest.

```
optim(initial_theta, cost, X = X, y = y)
```

should provide the same functionality as creating the extra function.